# How do I check if the previous command successfully executed or not using a script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

So i'm having a lot of trouble here... So say I want to type

```
useradd jamie
```

and then my current script is:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo Success; else echo ERROR: duplicate, try different name; fi
```

Well if I do another

```
useradd jamie
```

it should be echo'ing the error message. but instead it just says Success every time. I'm assuming this means i would have to have the input and the script in the same file? How should i go about this? If jamie is the only user in the system, then "useradd max" should echo "Success" as well which it does but it always echo's "Success". Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: First time, `useradd xxx; echo SS=$?` → `SS=0`. Second time, `useradd xxx; echo SS=$?` → `useradd: user 'xxx' already exists` and `SS=9`. Therefore there's something in your script that's not working properly, so you need to show us a **minimal example** (i.e. not your whole script, unless it's just a few lines) that illustrates the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every script is run in a *subshelll* so source the script instead of running it:

```
$ useradd jamie
useradd: user 'jamie' already exists
$ . script.sh
ERROR: duplicate, try different name
```

In Bash you can also use `source` instead of `.`.

Comment: This is how I have been executing the script. For example, I run ```./root/dir/script1.sh```

Comment: no, notice the space after `.`: `. /root/dir/script1.sh`

Comment: WOW thank you. i didnt know it was a simple space tripping me up this whole time